# React component not rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I have a file called `App.js` which is my application's main component.

I placed a new component in the result returned by that file's `render` method:

```
return (
    <div>
      <AjaxReq />
      //many other components
    </div>
);
```

Where `AjaxReq` is the following method:

```
'use strict';

var AjaxReq = React.createClass({

    loadDoc: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "someUrl",
            context: document.body,
            success: function(){
              $(this).addClass("done");
            }
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (<div>
            <p onClick={this.loadDoc}>
                Click this to make AJAX request.
            </p>
        </div>);
    }

});


module.exports = AjaxReq;
```

Unfortunately, this component is not rendered at all in the page.
Are there any issues with my code?

Comment: Only the AjaxReq is not displayed? also,are there any console errors?

Comment: Yes, only this one is not displayed. There are NO console errors.

Comment: You are missing the point of React if you are using jQuery to update the DOM. Update the `state` from your ajax response and let React re-render with the new class.

Comment: I will not use this in the final version of my code. I am just trying to test if an Ajax request works for querying a particular address.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this snippet `$(this).addClass("done");` does what you might intend to do.
In that context, **`this`** refers to the React Component (Virtual DOM), not the actual element in the DOM.

The only way to access a React Component instance outside of React is by storing the return value of `ReactDOM.render`.

Also by any chance,have you forgotten to import React (`var React = require('react')` ) into your AjaxReq module?

Answer (score 1):

Like phpcoderx said, not importing React could be causing nothing to render. To add the CSS class like you are trying to do, you would want to do something more like the following (though I don't think this would affect the lack of initial rendering issue you are seeing).

```
'use strict';

var AjaxReq = React.createClass({
    loadDoc: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "someUrl",
            context: document.body,
            success: function(){
                this.setState({ isLoaded: true });
            }
        });
    },

    getInitialState: function() {
        return { isLoaded: false };
    },

    render: function() {
        var classname = this.state.isLoaded ? 'done' : '';

        return (<div className={classname}>
            <p onClick={this.loadDoc}>
                Click this to make AJAX request.
            </p>
        </div>);
    };
});

module.exports = AjaxReq;
```

Comment: Not importing React is not an issue, because I solve that within the build process.  Why are you setting state here? If I copy paste the code, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoaded' of null`.

Comment: I'm setting state within the AJAX call as a way of keeping track of when whatever you're fetching has loaded (to avoid manipulating anything directly using jQuery). I'm not sure what your specific use case is, but I'll edit my post to add `getInitialState` - it should fix your problem.